External hard drive not available with Ubuntu 24.04
When I try to access my hard drive with file manager
I get this.

Importantly I can access this external disk on the same computer with Windows (dual boot) and with an other computer with Ubuntu 22.04.
Here is what I got.

Note:
C195-3A74 is an other hard drive with no problem.
With Ubuntu 22.04 the "missing" hard drive was visible as /media/fenaux/TOSHIBA EXT
Translation of error message is:
The special device /dev/sdb/sdb1 does not exist (a path prefix is ​​not a directory). 
dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

When running
sudo lsblk -f
I get
NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL         UUID        FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda
└─sda1
ntfs         TOSHIBA EXT   BC2CF6852CF639CA
As suggest in
Why do I get "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock" error?
I run
sudo apt install nfs-common
and it doesn't solve the problem. Please note that windows partition is also classified as ntfs and I can access it

in terminal type sudo lsblk -f and edit the result in to your question. This will show the FS type and mount points in better detail and confirm that the mount points indeed exist

It should be just /dev/sdb1

Also, if something's still wrong and you need to post some output (please don't add it as an image, but rather as text), run export LC_ALL=C to "set the running shell's language to english"

@mikewhatever thanks /dev/sdb1 works and I can access disk content with Nautilus. but this make Windows partition unavailable. At the next restart external disk is unavailable again and Windows partition is available. and again, this is specific with Ubuntu 24.04

@graham I run  sudo lsblk -f and added the result. No mount point appears

@karel As suggest in Why do I get "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock" error?
I run sudo apt install nfs-common and it doesn't solve the problem. Please note that windows partition is also classified as ntfs and I can access it

I dual boot Ubuntu 24.04 and Windows. I had a very similar problem with a 1TB Samsung NVMe external USB drive after updating to Ubuntu 24.04. I have a Lenovo T14s Gen4 AMD laptop. It worked OK sometimes, sometimes I could not mount or access it, but it was seen by Ubuntu.
I read that there are some problems with the ntfs "driver" in Ubuntu, causing problems with the ntfs file system, and that the recommended solution was to disable the current version of the driver in Ubuntu as a workaround to prevent this problem from reoccurring. This is done by creating a file by this command in terminal:
echo 'blacklist ntfs3' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/disable-ntfs3.conf

Then reboot. This forces Ubuntu to use the older, reliably working ntfs driver. When the problem is eventually solved in Ubuntu, this workaround should be easily reversed by deleting the disable-ntfs3.conf file just created in /etc/modprobe.d/ with the command above.
I also booted into Windows and inserted the drive to check and fix if there was problems with the file system on it (just because it was easier for me at the time, the same can be done in Ubuntu). Windows did some quick fix automatically when inserting the drive.
The external drive has been working fine in Ubuntu since.
